# Pushing problem using arrays of a struct into an array of another struct

Tags: solidity, remix

I want to count the votes of the candidates in general to say who is the winner (easy) and to count the votes of the candidates in each election center (here is my struggle). In latest version  0.8.7 I got errors like `"Copying of type struct memory[] memory to storage not yet supported" and "length is readonly..."` etc. I decided to work with version 0.4.25 wich I saw there wasn't the same problem. But here, even though the compiler is ok it doesn't show the third argument at the "centers" wich should be the array of candidates with their votes in the certain center. Here is the part of the code that I believe there is the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Election {

uint public totalVotes;

struct Candidate {
    string name;
    uint voteCount;
}
Candidate[] public candidates;
struct Voter {
    bool authorized;
    bool voted;
    bool center_sel; // if the voter has selected a center or not
    uint cen;        // the center he chooses
    uint vote;   // the candidate he chooses to vote
} 
mapping(address => Voter) public voters;

struct Center {
    string name;       // The name of the Center
    uint numOfVoters;  // The number of the voters that are going to vote in the specific Center
    Candidate[] cands; // array of all candidates with their votes in a certain center 
}
Center[] public centers;

function addCandidate(string memory _name) public {
    candidates.push(Candidate(_name, 0));
}

function addCenter(string memory _cenName) public {

    require(centers.length < 3); // We need max 3 centers
    centers.length++;
    Center storage C = centers[centers.length - 1];

    C.name = _cenName;
    C.numOfVoters = 0;

   for (uint i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
       C.cands.push(candidates[i]);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Ignore ownerOnly...forgot to remove it

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the default getter for `centers` doesn't return `cands` field. It was a limitation in the EVM, the solution is to write your own getter and return the data you need.

I'd recommend fixing solidity 0.8 instead of downgrading to 0.4.